# IONIC4 Angular PWA standalone is not refreshing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to create a PWA with IONIC Angular (web).

The application is running on: https://todo-ionic.thehangrycoder.now.sh

When I open the url on an iphone via Safari, it does asks me to add to homescreen.
The icons and splashscreens are also working. So far so good.

Now, when I make a change and deploy again. The standalone version doesn't notify me to refresh it.
But when I open the url on the same iphone device in safari, it does asks me to refresh the application.

Also, when the application starts in the mobile browser, it will perform an api request to get data (https://todo.thehangrycoder.now.sh/todo/).
But when I open the standalone application, it looks like it doesn't do the api request.

This is my nsgw config:
https://github.com/fransyozef/todo-challenge/blob/master/frontend/ionic4/todo-app/src/ngsw-config.json

and my manifest:
https://github.com/fransyozef/todo-challenge/blob/master/frontend/ionic4/todo-app/src/manifest.json

The application is deployed on NOW:
https://github.com/fransyozef/todo-challenge/blob/master/frontend/ionic4/todo-app/now.json

Any suggestions I can try? Or is here something I'm missing?

Comment: What do you mean by the standalone version? is that from the homescreen launch vs url in safari?

Comment: are you expecting a notification as a push notification, or do you mean your own custom on swUpdate code?

Comment: yeah "standalone" is the one that is placed from safari using the add to home screen. Then an icon will placed on the homescreen and when tapped, the application starts as "standalone" (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest).

as for notification. Thats the service worker notification (so NOT push). I subscribe to this event : https://github.com/fransyozef/todo-challenge/blob/276e245b89fc90d0d588e38a322dacb69318f090/frontend/ionic4/todo-app/src/app/app.component.ts#L72

Answer (score 0):

so I got an workaround (at least for the checking the version number).

I do an interval of 20 seconds to invoke the servic worker checkForUpdate() method.

https://github.com/fransyozef/todo-challenge/blob/25047e2add4ae1c570316a7c51ee6811d8b85bbf/frontend/ionic4/todo-app/src/app/app.component.ts#L42

This wil also reload the whole application (and get new api data). But when there is no new update, it will still not get new api data. Just found out that ios just saves the state of the standalone pwa application as is.